# two std::cout, only one outputting

Tags: c++, cout

I have a program which accepts input for 10 people, and is then supposed to cout the person who consumed the highest number of pancakes and the person who ate the fewest. I've tried:

- std::endl; at the end of every cout.
- std::flush; at the end.
- after this didn't work on my machine, I put the code into repl.it, and it still didn't work. This (from my understanding of how repl.it works) rules out an issue with compiler/ide (which is g++ and visual studio 2019).

My code:

main.cpp:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>
    #include "header.h"

    std::vector<int> person = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    std::vector<int> num_eaten_pancakes(10);

    int most_pancakes = 0;
    int least_pancakes = 0;
    int person_who_ate_most = 0;
    int person_who_ate_least = 0;

     int main() {
       get_nums_of_pancakes();
       person_who_ate_most = who_ate_most();
       std::cout << "Person " << who_ate_most() << " ate the most pancakes with " << num_eaten_pancakes[person_who_ate_most - 1] << " eaten." << std::flush;

       person_who_ate_least = who_ate_least();
       std::cout << "Person " << who_ate_least() << " ate the least pancakes with " << num_eaten_pancakes[person_who_ate_least - 1] << " eaten." << std::flush;
       return 0;
    }
```

funcs.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "header.h"

void get_nums_of_pancakes() {
//Get the no. of pancakes eaten by person 1, 2, etc. up to person 10.
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    person[i] = i + 1;
    std::cout << "Input the number of pancakes entered by person " << person[i] << ": ";
    std::cin >> num_eaten_pancakes[i];
  }
}

//Who ate the most pancakes
int who_ate_most() {
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (num_eaten_pancakes[i] > most_pancakes) {
        most_pancakes = num_eaten_pancakes[i];
        person_who_ate_most = person[i];
    }
  }
  return person_who_ate_most;
}

//Who ate the least pancakes
int who_ate_least() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     do
        least_pancakes = num_eaten_pancakes[i];
     while (i == 0);

     if (num_eaten_pancakes[i] < least_pancakes) {
         least_pancakes = num_eaten_pancakes[i];
         person_who_ate_least = person[i];
     }
   }
   return person_who_ate_least;
 }
```

header.h

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

//VARIABLES
//Vectors for 10 people, pancakes
extern std::vector<int> person;
extern std::vector<int> num_eaten_pancakes;

extern int most_pancakes;
extern int least_pancakes;
extern int person_who_ate_most;
extern int person_who_ate_least;

//FUNCTIONS
void get_nums_of_pancakes();
int who_ate_most();
int who_ate_least();
```

The output, when I enter the number of pancakes consumed, is correct for the person who ate the most, but when it comes to the person who consumed the fewest, there's nothing.

Comment: Have you tried to use a debugger to step through the code statement by statement to see what really happens? If not then now is the perfect time to do that, and to learn how to use one of the most important tools besides the compiler itself.

Comment: `do least_pancakes = num_eaten_pancakes[i]; while (i == 0);` This won't finish any time soon.

Comment: "This doesn't print anything" != "My program never finishes"

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm not really sure how to use the debugger. At the moment I just hit the button and check if it works lol. I'd really like to learn how to use it properly, though. Do you have any resources for learning how to use it? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an infinite do-while-loop in `who_ate_least()`: If `i == 0` you never change `i` and never make the condition become false.

Answer (score 3):

You got infinite-loop at this part, so the function `who_ate_least` stucked.

```
     do
        least_pancakes = num_eaten_pancakes[i];
     while (i == 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change "who_ate_least()" function as follows:

```
int who_ate_least() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     if(i==0)
        least_pancakes = num_eaten_pancakes[i];

     if (num_eaten_pancakes[i] <= least_pancakes) {
         least_pancakes = num_eaten_pancakes[i];
         person_who_ate_least = person[i];
     }
   }
   return person_who_ate_least;
 }
```